# Netbeans F2 Keystroke Not Functioning When Selecting A Record In JTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, keystroke

I have this application that can edit a record of an employee and to do that, the user can click that specific record and press the Edit Button or the user can just press the shortcut key in the keyboard that I created which is the F2. Here is my code:

```
btn_EditEmployee.getInputMap(btn_EditEmployee.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), "btn_EditEmployee");
   btn_EditEmployee.getActionMap().put("btn_EditEmployee", new AbstractAction() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //my code for editing an employee
   }
});
```

but my problem is the F2 keystroke that I created is not working if I click a record on a table. Can someone tell me why it is not working, please. Thanks in advance for answering.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that F1, F3-F12 are working with my code above when I select a record on a JTable. The only problem is the F2. I'm insisting on using F2 as an Edit Action because my F1 is the Create Action on my application.

Answer (score 1):

> or the user can just press the shortcut key in the keyboard that I created which is the F2.

You have a couple of problems:

1. Your code is using F1 as the KeyStroke, not F2.
2. You are using the InputMap/ActionMap of the button, not the table. You should be doing the KeyBindings for the table, not the button.
3. You should NOT be creating two Actions. Instead you create a single Action that can be shared by the button and the table.

So the basic code would be:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction(...)
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // add logic here
    }
};

JButton button = new JButton( action );

String key = "EditAction"
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, 0);
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(ks, key);
table.getActionMap().put(key, action);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to edit the F1 into F2. I will try this code right now and see if it works. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: Thanks again for the reply but I'm a beginner and don't know much about key binding or keystroke. Would you mind if you can you please tell me how to add this code step by step. That Action code is new to me. I don't know what to write in 'new EditAction(...);'

Comment: @TheAnonymous94 carefully because F2 is built_in accelerator (KeyBindings in API) for TableCellEditor

Comment: @mKorbel oh I see... is it possible to override that built in F2 accelerator in JTable and create my own sir? I really don't know how to do it. I hope you can help me sir. In the code above that camickr provided, I don't know what expression should I put in the 
Action action = new EditAction(???); so that I can try it.

Comment: @TheAnonymous94 yes thats possible, but F2 is implemented as crossplatform editor (from any XxxOffice to texteditors - e.g. notepad), this is can confusing an user, you can to remove this value from UIManager, call null to startEditing (I'm sure thats a few times here with as an SSCCE / MCVE), or you can to override  startEditing for XxxTableCellEditor and by using fireXxxXxx from SwingAction(ActionLIstener) / KeyBindings

Comment: `That Action code is new to me` - you are already extending AbstractAction so you just need to make a class so you can reuse the Action. See edit. Also you can check out the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). `please tell me how to add this code step by step` - I already did that. I gave you 3 steps. `is it possible to override that built in F2 accelerator in JTable` - the 3 steps I gave you show you how to do this. But, I agree with mKorbel, you should choose a different KeyStroke and keep the default bindings.